# How can I replace the little camera icon at bottom of lock screen (no root)?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, lock-screens, xolo

Hi Android enthusiasts,

I have Xolo Era X1 running Android 6.0

My lock screen unlocks by swiping upwards. Now there are 2 icons at the bottom, one launches Google talking girl and the other opens camera.

Because I'm right handed I accidentally launch camera while unlocking.

How can I remove that camera launcher icon from lock screen? Or how can I replace it with Reddit icon?

Comment: http://tunecomp.net/change-remove-lockscreen-shortcuts-android-6-7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove it from your lock screen. You can use a lock screen app instead, to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

go to Settings - > Lock Screen & Security - > info and app shortcuts

from there you can set which apps appears for each side

as somebody already commented, your other option would be installing a new lock screen app

edit: from the last page i screenshotted below, you could set the rt side app to be a browser with reddit.com as its homepage

[image: find settings][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Is it a custom ROM? Or what's this phone???

Comment: is a Samsung galaxy s7 active on at&t stock rom, updated Android, no root. i just have nova Launcher & the coolest free space theme I could find, so the colors are different but you should find the same options